# Simple CLI Python Hangman game

Tags: python, game, hangman, python-2.x

Preamble: I am very new to Python, and outside of Googling functions and a former work colleague telling me why I'm wrong, I have no formal training and haven't taken any "Learn Python" courses.

I have written a CLI Hangman game which selects a random word from a ~7000-line list of words (in another file called wordlist.txt), and you have to guess the word within a set number of attempts.

I would really appreciate some input into how I can follow normal Python coding practices better; my experience is in other languages so I tried my best to follow general coding standards but beyond that I just followed what PyCharm suggested I should improve - I am not looking for improvements in things like functionality; I am more looking for improvements in code style and best practices.

Below is my code. There is another file which this is called from (if you select the correct menu item), `Menu.py`, hence no `Hangman()` at the end:

```
import os


class Hangman(object):
    input_letter = []
    word_to_guess = []
    DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    DICTIONARY = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "wordlist.txt")
    FILE = open(DICTIONARY, "r")
    list_of_words = []
    mutable_hidden_word = []
    count = 0
    game_complete = False
    wrong_guesses = []
    number_of_guesses = 0
    HANGED_MAN = {
        0: "     \n    |      \n    |      \n    |      \n    |       \n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        1: "     _______\n    |      \n    |      \n    |      \n    |       \n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        2: "     _______\n    |/      \n    |      \n    |      \n    |       \n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        3: "     _______\n    |/      |\n    |      \n    |      \n    |       \n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        4: "     _______\n    |/      |\n    |      (_)\n    |      \n    |       \n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        5: "     _______\n    |/      |\n    |      (_)\n    |       |\n    |       |\n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        6: "     _______\n    |/      |\n    |      (_)\n    |      \\|\n    |       |\n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        7: "     _______\n    |/      |\n    |      (_)\n    |      \\|/\n    |       |\n    |      \n    |\n____|________\n",
        8: "     _______\n    |/      |\n    |      (_)\n    |      \\|/\n    |       |\n    |      / \n    |\n____|________\n",
        9: "     _______\n    |/      |\n    |      (_)\n    |      \\|/\n    |       |\n    |      / \\\n    |\n____|________\n"
    }

    def __init__(self):
        print "Welcome to Hangman!"
        self.reset_all()
        self.add_words_to_list()
        self.get_random_word(self.list_of_words, self.read_word_list_length(self.DICTIONARY))
        self.FILE.close()
        self.create_hidden_word(self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess, ""))
        while not self.game_complete:
            os.system('clear')
            self.play_game()
        play_again = raw_input("Play again? (y/n)\n> ").lower()
        if play_again == "y":
            Hangman()


    # SETUP FUNCTIONS
    def reset_all(self):
        self.word_to_guess = []
        self.wrong_guesses = []
        self.mutable_hidden_word = []
        self.game_complete = False
        self.count = 0
        self.number_of_guesses = 0
        self.input_letter = []


    def add_words_to_list(self):
        if not self.list_of_words:
            for line in self.FILE:
                self.list_of_words.append(line)


    @staticmethod
    def read_word_list_length(fileName):
        with open(fileName) as f:
            i = -1
            for i, l in enumerate(f, 1):
                pass
        return i


    @staticmethod
    def mk_string(word, inbetween=""):
        return inbetween.join(word)


    def get_random_word(self, listOfWords, wordListLength):
        from random import randint
        randomWord = randint(0, wordListLength-1)
        word = listOfWords[randomWord].replace("\n", "")
        for char in word:
            self.word_to_guess.extend(char)


    def create_hidden_word(self, wordToHide):
        for char in range(0, len(wordToHide)):
            self.mutable_hidden_word.append("_")


    # GAMEPLAY FUNCTIONS
    def play_game(self):
        if "_" in self.mutable_hidden_word:
            self.print_hanged_man()
            self.print_hidden_word()
            self.print_wrong_guesses()
            self.take_player_guess()
            self.check_player_guess(self.input_letter[0])
            self.number_of_guesses += 1
            if self.count == 9:
                self.print_hanged_man()
                self.print_hidden_word()
                self.print_wrong_guesses()
                print "You lose!"
                print "Correct word: " + self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess)
                self.game_complete = True
        else:
            self.print_hanged_man()
            self.print_hidden_word()
            print "Congratulations, you win! Your word was \"%s\". It took you %d guesses to win."\
                  % (self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess), self.number_of_guesses)
            self.game_complete = True


    def take_player_guess(self):
        player_input = raw_input("\nInput a letter: >>  ")
        if len(player_input) > 1:
            self.take_player_guess()
        else:
            self.input_letter.insert(0, player_input)


    def check_player_guess(self, guess):
        if guess not in self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess):
            self.count += 1
            self.wrong_guesses.append(guess)
        else:
            for letter in range(0, len(self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess))):
                if self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess)[letter] == guess:
                    self.mutable_hidden_word[letter] = guess

    def print_hidden_word(self):
        print self.mk_string(self.mutable_hidden_word, " ")


    def print_wrong_guesses(self):
        if not self.wrong_guesses == []:
            print "Wrong guesses: " + self.mk_string(self.wrong_guesses, ", ")


    def print_hanged_man(self):
        try:
            print self.HANGED_MAN[self.count]
        except KeyError:
            print "Dictionary key is invalid!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 notes :

1) add more docstrings for comments 
from

```
def check_player_guess(self, guess):
    if guess not in self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess):
        ...
```

to

```
def check_player_guess(self, guess):
    """what does it do? params"""
    if guess not in self.mk_string(self.word_to_guess):
        ...
```

take it as a good practise though i must congratulate you on your judicious namings

2) use @classmethod
will reduce some bloats

from

```
def play_game(self):
    if "_" in self.mutable_hidden_word:
        self.print_hanged_man()
        self.print_hidden_word()
        self.print_wrong_guesses()
        self.take_player_guess()
        self.check_player_guess(self.input_letter[0])
        self.number_of_guesses += 1
```

to

```
@classmethod
def play_game():
    ...
        print_hanged_man()
        print_hidden_word()
        print_wrong_guesses()
        take_player_guess()
        check_player_guess(self.input_letter[0])
        number_of_guesses += 1
```

if @classmethod was also used on them (i.e print_ ...)

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! I have been reading up on @classmethod vs instance methods and while I understand their differences, I don't understand which (if either) would have any obvious benefits over the other in my scenario. Is there any real benefit of using @classmethod here over using instance methods, other than the removal of `self.`, or is it purely an aesthetic or personal choice in this scenario? Apologies if this question has an obvious; I am still learning!

Comment: @JamesWhiteley makes logic more evident